# Reading in a XML data file into a JDBC

Tags: xml, jdbc

I'm trying to populate a table by reading in a XML file using Java, but I don't know where to start. Do I use FileInputStream?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jaxb library to read xml. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186896/how-do-i-parse-this-xml-in-java-with-jaxb) question for an example. Another [example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/) for reading xml using jaxb.

After you've read the xml file, you can populate the data into the relevant tables using jdbc.

Please expand your question if this approach does not solve your problem.