# Storing XML as flat file in HBASE

Tags: java, xml, parsing, hadoop, hbase

I am new to HBase and I want to know how this can be done. I have the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<interestRateCurve>
<effectiveasof>2016-04-27</effectiveasof>
<currency>JPY</currency>
<baddayconvention>M</baddayconvention>

<deposits>
<daycountconvention>ACT/360</daycountconvention>
<snaptime>2016-04-26T07:00:00.000Z</snaptime>
<spotdate>2016-04-29</spotdate>

<calenders>
<calender>TYO</calender>
</calenders>

<curvepoint>
<tenor>1M</tenor>
<maturitydate>2016-05-30</maturitydate>
<parrate>-0.00066</parrate>
</curvepoint>

<curvepoint>
<tenor>2M</tenor>
<maturitydate>2016-06-29</maturitydate>
<parrate>-0.00042</parrate>
</curvepoint>

<curvepoint>
<tenor>3M</tenor>
<maturitydate>2016-07-29</maturitydate>
<parrate>-0.000386</parrate>
</curvepoint>

<curvepoint>
<tenor>6M</tenor>
<maturitydate>2016-10-31</maturitydate>
<parrate>-0.000114</parrate>
</curvepoint>

<curvepoint>
<tenor>1Y</tenor>
<maturitydate>2017-04-28</maturitydate>o
<parrate>0.000758</parrate>
</curvepoint>

</deposits>

<swaps>
<fixeddaycountconvention>ACT/365</fixeddaycountconvention>
<floatingdaycountconvention>ACT/360</floatingdaycountconvention>
<fixedpaymentfrequency>6M</fixedpaymentfrequency>
<floatingpaymentfrequency>6M</floatingpaymentfrequency>
<snaptime>2016-04-26T07:00:00.000Z</snaptime>
<spotdate>2016-04-29</spotdate>

<calenders>
<calendar>TYO</calendar>
</calenders>

<curvepoint>
<tenor>2Y</tenor>
<maturitydate>2018-04-29</maturitydate>
<parrate>-0.0016</parrate>
</curvepoint>

<curvepoint>
<tenor>3Y</tenor>
<maturitydate>2019-04-29</maturitydate>
<parrate>-0.001663</parrate>
</curvepoint>

<curvepoint>
<tenor>4Y</tenor>
<maturitydate>2020-04-29</maturitydate>
<parrate>-0.001388</parrate>
</curvepoint>

<curvepoint>
<tenor>5Y</tenor>
<maturitydate>2021-04-29</maturitydate>
<parrate>-0.000963</parrate>
</curvepoint>

<curvepoint>
<tenor>6Y</tenor>
<maturitydate>2022-04-29</maturitydate>
<parrate>-0.000475</parrate>
</curvepoint>

<curvepoint>
<tenor>7Y</tenor>
<maturitydate>2023-04-29</maturitydate>
<parrate>-0.0000063</parrate>
</curvepoint>

<curvepoint>
<tenor>8Y</tenor>
<maturitydate>2024-04-29</maturitydate>
<parrate>0.000425</parrate>
</curvepoint>
<curvepoint>
<tenor>9Y</tenor>
<maturitydate>2025-04-29</maturitydate>
<parrate>0.000813</parrate>
</curvepoint>
<curvepoint>
<tenor>10Y</tenor>
<maturitydate>2026-04-29</maturitydate>
<parrate>0.0012</parrate>
</curvepoint>

<curvepoint>
<tenor>12Y</tenor>
<maturitydate>2028-04-29</maturitydate>
<parrate>0.002038</parrate>
</curvepoint>

<curvepoint>
<tenor>15Y</tenor>
<maturitydate>2031-04-29</maturitydate>
<parrate>0.00315</parrate>
</curvepoint>
<curvepoint>
<tenor>20Y</tenor>
<maturitydate>2036-04-29</maturitydate>
<parrate>0.004588</parrate>
</curvepoint>

<curvepoint>
<tenor>30Y</tenor>
<maturitydate>2046-04-29</maturitydate>
<parrate>0.005688</parrate>
</curvepoint>
</swaps>
</interestRateCurve>
```

I want to store it as a table in HBase in the following format:

```
RowID      |  Deposit-1M | Deposit-2M |....| Swaps-2Y| Swaps-3Y | ....|Swaps-30Y
2016-04-27_JPY | val1 | val2 |.......
```

So, I want to store it as a single column with values for each tag under `<curvepoint>` for `Deposits-1M` (where `1M` is the `<tenor>` value). And similarly for `Swaps`.

Please tell me how do I do it in Java. I just cannot understand!!

Comment: You understand there are 2 distinct steps here: 1) parse the XML and convert it to a string in the format you'd like and 2) store that string into HBase.  Am I right ?

Comment: @RobertoCongiu Could you tell me how do I convert the XML to the required format? Can JAXB do that?

Comment: Yes, JAXB would be one way to do it, using annotation and creating Java objects for the different parts of the document. Then you can use those objects to build the output you need. See this other question for an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186896/how-do-i-parse-this-xml-in-java-with-jaxb